# Laravel Facade error: Non-static method should not be called statically

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-facade

I have a simple modal having an index method to get data from DB

**Modal:** Nation

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Nation extends Model{
  function index(){
     Nation::where(['visible'=>1])->get();
  }
}
```

Now I want to call this function from a controller:

**Controller**:

> ```
>  $nations = Nation::index();
> ```

To make this I created a Facade in this way:

1. Created a Provider
2. Registered the provider in config/app.php
3. Created the Facade
4. Registered the Alias in config/app.php

**Step 1 - Provider**:

> php artisan make:provider NationServiceProvider

```
public function register()    {
    $this->app->bind('nation',function(){
        return new Nation();
    });
}
```

**Step 2**:  Register the provider in config/app.php

In providers array:

> ```
>     App\Providers\NationServiceProvider::class,
> ```

**Step 3** Create the Facade

I created a folder App/Facades/ and inside the file **NationFacade.php**

```
namespace App\Facades;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class NationFacade extends Facade{
protected static function getFacadeAccessor(){
    return 'nation';
   }
}
```

**Step 4**:  Register the alias in config/app.php

In Aliases array:

> ```
>     'Nation' => App\Facades\NationFacade::class
> ```

But, when I run the controller I got the error:

> ```
> "message": "Non-static method App\\Models\\Nation::index() should not be called statically",
> ```

I also tried to clear cache and composer dump. What I'm missing here?

Thanks for any sugegstion!

Comment: In your nation model, make the index function public.

Comment: Try calling without the alias. ie) `NationFacade::index()`. AFAIK, the call is directly happening from `Nation` model which should not be happening. Call should happen in the facade and it should resolve the method and call it.

Comment: @NazmulAbedin, thanks! I was missing it.

Comment: @CerlinBoss. Without Alias I got a not found! So I realized the 'use' was missing (I thought it was made by the bootstrap). If I add the 'use App\Facades\NationFacade;' It works! But now I'm confused: what I have to use w ith the alias?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, when you use a class without namespace, php assumes the file should be in the same directory as current file. Only when it doesn't find, it calls the `__autoload` magic method. Laravel's/Composer's resolving logic sits inside `__autoload` method (this is the place where Laravel resolves the alias which you have registered with it).

In your case, php detects a class with same name residing in its reach so it tries to use that.

Solutions are

1. Change the Alias to some class which is not current directory. In this case you have already named the facade a different name, so just use that

   ```
   // Register alias
   'NationFacade' => App\Facades\NationFacade::class

   // Call it like
   NationFacade::index()
   ```

   **OR**

   ```
   // Import
   use App\Facades\NationFacade

   // Call it like
   NationFacade::index()
   ```
2. Use php's namespace with alias instead of Laravel's alias (i am not 100% sure if this will work)

   ```
   // Import the facade
   use App\Facades\NationFacade as Nation;

   // Call it like
   Nation::index()
   ```

If you still have doubts, please feel free to comment down below

Answer (score 4):

Only you need change 'public' for 'static'

Comment: Great answer! Short and sweet.  Was looking for a way to use custom methods within Model.  Your answer made it happen.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed similar issue by adding `static` to my function:

```
public function foo() {}
```

to

```
public static function foo() {}
```